# Reduce the amount of `if` through variables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As divide correctly `if` through variables

Soon the code will turn into this (there will be a lot of `if` values)

```
if
 if
  if
   if
    if
     if
      if
       if
       else
      else
     else
    else
   else
  else
 else
else
```

...

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool onlyInstance;
        Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "AppName", out onlyInstance);
        if (onlyInstance)
        {
            var whitelist = new HashSet<string> { ".txt" };
            if (args.Any() && whitelist.Contains(Path.GetExtension(args[0])))
            {
                args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
                if (args.Length > 1)
                {
                    string filePath = args[1];
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    string fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
                    string fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                    string fileFolderDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
                    string newFileName = String.Format("{0}.my1", fileName);
                    string createFolderIn = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\AppName\\Copy\\");
                    string dstPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\AppName\\Copy\\") + newFileName;
                    string systemFolderLS = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\System32");
                    string systemFolderLs = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\system32");
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(createFolderIn);
                    File.Copy(filePath, dstPath, true);
                    if ((fileFolderDir == systemFolderLS) || (fileFolderDir == systemFolderLs))
                    {
                        Process ProcAll = new Process();
                        ProcAll.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
                        ProcAll.StartInfo.FileName = fileNameNoExt + ".exe";
                        ProcAll.Start();
                        Application.Exit();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                        Application.Run(new Form1());
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Application.Exit();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does "Help divide correctly `if` through variables" mean?

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You don't need so many `Application.Exit`. Returning from `Main` method is enough.

Comment: Too much `if` you need to sort the code... `switch` and `case` unsuitable

Comment: Learn skills. Anyone can lay bricks, but can you do it accurately, quickly, cleanly etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can do is reduce nesting.

**Disclaimer** : This is totally opinion based.

```
Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "AppName", out bool onlyInstance);

if (!onlyInstance)
   return;

var whitelist = new HashSet<string> { ".txt" };

if (!args.Any() || !whitelist.Contains(Path.GetExtension(args[0])))
   return;

args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();

// also this is redundant 
//if (args.Length <= 1)
//   return;

var filePath = args[1];
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
var fileNameNoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
var fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath); // this is never used
var fileFolderDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath);
var newFileName = $"{fileName}.my1";
var createFolderIn = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\AppName\\Copy\\");
var dstPath = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%\\AppName\\Copy\\") + newFileName;

// not sure why you have 2 of these but its ugly and looks redundent
var systemFolderLS = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\System32"); 
var systemFolderLs = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SystemRoot%\\system32");
Directory.CreateDirectory(createFolderIn);
File.Copy(filePath, dstPath, true);

if (fileFolderDir == systemFolderLS || fileFolderDir == systemFolderLs)
{
   var ProcAll = new Process();
   ProcAll.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
   ProcAll.StartInfo.FileName = fileNameNoExt + ".exe";
   return;
}

Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

**Disclaimer 2** :Totally untested, so I am not responsible for the people you maim or otherwise harm with this code

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the code. The folder `System32` has a big letter and a small one `system32`

Comment: Error: `Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "AppName", out bool onlyInstance);` in the text bool onlyInstance

Comment: @Vitokhv you must not be using the Latest C#, well just do this     `bool onlyInstance;`
`Mutex mtx = new Mutex(true, "AppName", out onlyInstance);`

Comment: Does not want to run system files through self, I'll see what's wrong later, thanks

Comment: @ChrisF thanks for the edits :) thought the OCD comment was gold

Comment: @TheGeneral it was flagged as rude. I thought I'd save you from the 100 point rep hit.